# how to list up all directory and files (include sub directory) without access right?

Tags: cmd, compare, backup, robocopy, fileserver

I bought a new file server.

I want to copy all file and directories.

I tried this.

`cmd
robocopy d:\ \\10.226.0.12\full_backup\ /R:3 /E /ZB /COPYALL /LOG:backup_log.txt`

Then, we have to compare file and directories, for find missing copy file.

I tried  this.

`cmd
tree d:\ /F > out.txt`

But, administrator can't access any file and directories.

what should i do?

robocopy is using "Backup Operators".

I think, use "tree" command with "Backup Operators", then perfect work.

Comment: Which Windows version(s) on server(s)? Off topic: to **compare** _files and directories_ I'd use `dir /B /S /A /O:NE d:\*.*` rather than `tree`.

Comment: solved. http://qiita.com/kagasu/items/d6d41a9209c709866455

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser/help/self-answer) (and answer in English ... your link appears to be in Japanese)

Answer (score 0):

there is the problem with administrators group can not access any file and folders.

How to solve this.

1. take ownership.

   `bat
   takeown /F D:\ /A /R /D Y`
2. list up files. (thx for this command. JosefZ)

   `bat
   dir /B /S /A /O:NE d:\*.*`

In other words, you don't turn off administrators group access. forever.

Even if there is any reason.